# Unix command to delete 4th column in a comma delimited file?

Tags: regex, unix

I am dealing with a huge data file and getting an extra column in the file which I don't require. It is a comma delimited file.

Comment: What does this file look like?  Why does the 4th column pose a problem for you?

Comment: Its a data file and I don't need the fourth column : specifically :

Comment: give a sample data and expected output, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. and show your attempt at solving it

Comment: If your loading the file into a DB, just up the input.cfg to skip that column? Will be much faster than having to rewrite the file with 1 column less. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

if the first three columns are not quoted strings that may contain commas, then just do this:

```
cut -d, -f1-3,5- < originalfile > newfile
```

*Edit: fixed stupid typo (correct: `-f`, was: `-c`)*

Comment: "Name", "Address", "Mobile", "Fax", "Lane", "City"
"Max", "204 Top Hill", "7733392293", "5099229322", "Cross Street", "London"
"April", "09 Mint", "7239283783", "5300398302", "B4 Lane", "New York"

This is the kind of file, I do not want the 4th column and I am not loading it into DB

Comment: I think it should be `cut -d, -f1-3,5-`